# Finding OpenBLAS on Windows with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, openblas

I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio
for building and installing OpenBLAS, specifically 1. "Native (MSVC) ABI".
And now all the includes and libraries and CMake files are in `C:/opt` like it wanted.

I then saw I could use FindBLAS in my project's CMakeFile so I added
`FindBLAS()`, but apparently it's not a command?
I saw everyone who mentioned FindBLAS instead wrote:

```
set(BLA_VENDOR OpenBLAS)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
```

so I'm actually pretty confused. What is FindBLAS? Why can't I find any examples of anyone using it?

But then I tried the set and find_package route I saw everywhere and got:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:1346 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
```

I tried setting the environment variables, resetting, everything I can think of. I'm not sure why CMake refuses to find the library and update `${BLAS_LIBRARIES}`.

Comment: Did you solve? I didn't. Instruction is not actually instructive for me.

Comment: No, not yet. :(